# What is the purpose of a quantum RAM in quantum algorithms?

Tags: quantum-memory

I see many papers (e.g. [Quantum principal component analysis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0401.pdf)) in which the existence of qRAM is necessary. What's the actual purpose of qRAM in quantum algorithms?

Comment: Hello, we prefer it if one post contains only one question. Also *problems we will face* will probably lead to dicussion/opinions and is therefore not the best question for Quantum Computing StackExchange.

Comment: @MEE replaced two questions with one.

Comment: related to https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/115/55

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is discussed in chapter 5 of [Ciliberto *et al.*](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/474/2209/20170551#sec-6).

The purpose of most [quantum(-enhanced) machine learning algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_machine_learning#Quantum-enhanced_machine_learning) is to speed-up the processing of *classical* data over what is possible with *classical* machine learning algorithms.
In other words, the context is that you have a set of classical vectors $\{\boldsymbol x_k\}_k$, and you want to compute some function $\boldsymbol f(\boldsymbol x_k)$ of this data (which may then be used as an estimator of some property, or as a function characterising a classifier to be used for new data points, or something else).
Most quantum machine learning algorithms tell you that, provided you are able to efficiently perform the mapping 
$$\{\boldsymbol x_k\}_k\mapsto\lvert \{\boldsymbol x_k\}\rangle= N\sum_{kj} x_{kj}\lvert k,j\rangle,$$
then it is sometimes possible to compute $\boldsymbol f(\{\boldsymbol x_k\})$ more efficiently.
It is, however, highly nontrivial how to perform such mapping *efficiently*.

To maintain the potential exponential speed-ups of the quantum algorithms, this conversion needs to be efficient. If this is not the case, then one ends up in a situation in which the quantum algorithm can solve the problem very efficiently, but only after a lengthy preprocessing of the data has been performed, therefore killing the whole point of using the quantum algorithm.

This is where QRAMs come into play. 
A QRAM is a device that can (theoretically) encode $N$ $d$-dimensional classical vectors into (the amplitudes of) a quantum state of $\log(Nd)$ qubits, in time $\mathcal O(\log(Nd))$.
As discussed in [Ciliberto *et al.*](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/474/2209/20170551#sec-6), as well as in [this related answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1502/55), the actual feasibility of QRAMs is still not entirely clear, and many caveats remain.